# travis ci npm release error "missing api_key"

Tags: npm, travis-ci

See: https://travis-ci.org/Jeff-Tian/tplant/jobs/620447627

I have configured the `api_key` with

```
api_key: $NPM_TOKEN
```

and I am sure that the `NPM_TOKEN` was set and it can be verified by the `echo` command:
[image]
[image]

So who can help investigate where goes wrong?

The full travis ci config can be checked here:

https://travis-ci.org/Jeff-Tian/tplant/builds/620447623/config

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Finally found this thread: https://travis-ci.community/t/no-stash-entries-found-missing-api-key-failed-to-deploy/6029

And fixed by changing the travis.yml as per: https://github.com/Jeff-Tian/tplant/commit/0695ab29bff76a9da3300f549df32d10e4295daf

And opted out from beta by:

[image]

Comment: Same experience with [Kentico Kontent cli](https://travis-ci.com/Kentico/kontent-cli) - works after your change -THX

Comment: ...and [Gatsby source plugin for Kontent](https://github.com/Kentico/gatsby-source-kontent/commit/84be520765dc967e5b4b389421ab86ea192cc7bc)